# How do you search for exact terms (which may include special characters) with trailing/leading wildcard matching in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out how to create Elasticsearch queries that allow for exact matches containing reserved characters while supporting trailing or leading wildcard expansion. I am using logstash dynamic templates which automatically also creates a raw field for each of my terms.

To sum up as concisely as possible, I want to create queries that can support two generic types of matching across all values:

- Searching terms such as `'abc'` to return results like `'abc.xyz.com'`. In this case, the token created by the standard token analyzer completely tokenizes `'abc.xyz.com'` into one token, and wildcard matching can succeed using the following command:

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "wildcard": {
        "_all": "*abc*" 
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Searching terms such as fullpaths like `'/Intel/1938138191(1).zip'` to return results like `'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/1938138191(1).zip'`. In this case, even if I backslash all of the reserved characters, doing a wildcard match like

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "wildcard": {
        "_all": "*/Intel/1938138191(1).zip*" 
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  will not work. And this is because `_all` defaults to using the standard analyzer, so the path will be split and an exact match cannot be made. However, if I SPECIFICALLY query the raw field like below (both when I escape / do not escape the special characters), I get the correct result:

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "wildcard": {
        "field.raw": "*/Intel/1938138191(1).zip*" 
      }
    }
  }
  ```

So my question is, is there any way to support calling wildcard queries across both tokens analyzed by the standard analyzers and the raw fields which are not analyzed at all, in one query? That is some way of generically encapsulating searched terms so that in both of my above examples, I would get the correct result? For reference I am using Elasticsearch version 1.7. I have also tried looking into query string matching and term matching, all to no avail.